# What is "Monster Hunter Language" in the voice language selector?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

I started the game for the first time and I saw an option called "Monster Hunter Language" on the Voice Language Settings. What is it?

[image: Language Settings screenshot, showing "Monster Hunter Language" selected for Voice]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's exactly what it sounds like - the "language" spoken in previous Monster Hunter games, mostly consisting of grunts and short, made up words. It is voiced by the Japanese voice actors, and the monsters' names are in Japanese.

Comment: So, is like the [Simlish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simlish) of Monster Hunter? Interesting.

Comment: Essentially, or the voices in the Animal Crossing games.